# Under what circumstances would the two return values of crypto/rand read() ever be useful?

Tags: random, hash, go

The typical usage of crypto/rand goes something like this:

```
salt := make([]byte, saltLength)
n,err := rand.Read(salt)
```

Which fills the byte slice I have labeled "salt" here with a sequence of random bytes.

Under what circumstances might the random number generator fail?  Would it be insecure to fall back to a math/rand equivalent in the event that err is not nil?

Since the length of the byte slice is already known, n also seems useless to me, is there any reason I wouldn't just use _,err in its place?

Comment: If there is not enough entropy available to generate a "random" (whatever that means) number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be safe your code should look more like this:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    saltLength := 16
    salt := make([]byte, saltLength)
    n, err := rand.Read(salt[:cap(salt)])
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    salt = salt[:n]
    if len(salt) != saltLength {
        // handle error
    }
    fmt.Println(len(salt), salt)
}
```

Output:

```
16 [191 235 81 37 175 238 93 202 230 158 41 199 202 85 67 209]
```

`n` may be less than `len(salt)` if insufficient entropy is available. You should always check for errors.

For example, one of the many ways to obtain a sequence of random numbers is the `getrandom` system call on Linux or the `CryptGenRandom` API call on Windows.

References:

[random: introduce getrandom(2) system call](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c6e9d6f38894798696f23c8084ca7edbf16ee895)

[CryptGenRandom function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942.aspx)

ADDENDUM:

The `crypto/rand` package is a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator. Package `math/rand` is not cryptographically secure.

There are too many paths in even a simple program to test them all. Therefore, the only way to write programs with zero defects and zero bugs is to write readable, maintainable  code that is provably correct. Systematic Programming by Niklaus Wirth is a good primer. It's worthwhile to spend time on constructing a robust general form, which can easily be adapted to each special case and that is easily maintainable as requirements change.

For example, for the `io.Reader` interface, typical usage is a looping pattern.

```
func Reader(rdr io.Reader) error {
    bufLen := 256
    buf := make([]byte, bufLen)
    for {
        n, err := rdr.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])
        if n == 0 {
            if err == nil {
                continue
            }
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }
        buf = buf[:n]
        // process read buffer
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

> [type Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)
>
> ```
> type Reader interface {
>         Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
> }
> ```
>
> Reader is the interface that wraps the basic Read method.
>
> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes
>   read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read
>   returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the
>   call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read
>   conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.
>
> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after
>   successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read.
>   It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the
>   error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general
>   case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end
>   of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The
>   next Read should return 0, EOF regardless.
>
> Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before
>   considering the error err. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that
>   happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF
>   behaviors.
>
> Implementations of Read are discouraged from returning a zero byte
>   count with a nil error, and callers should treat that situation as a
>   no-op.

We only want to allocate the buffer once, before we start the `Read` loop. However, we want the compiler and runtime to detect if we stray outside the valid buffer length `n` in the `Read` loop, so we write `buf = buf[:n]`. However, when we loop to the next `Read` we explicitly want the full buffer: `buf[:cap(buf)`.

It's never wrong to write `Read(buf[:cap(buf)])`. Even though you may not have a `Read` loop now, you may add one later, and you may forget to reset the buffer length. There may be special case for a particular `Read` implementation, like an underlying `ReadFull`. Now you have to read and monitor the underlying code to prove that your code is correct. Documentation is not always reliable. And you can't safely switch to another `io.Reader` `Read` implementation.

When you access the `salt` slice, `salt[:len(salt)]`, you are using `len(salt)` not `n`. If they differ, you have a bug.

> "implementations should follow a general principle of robustness: be
>   conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from
>   others." [Jon
>   Postel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  So am I to assume that using math/rand as a fallback if crypto/rand failed would be insecure?  Can you explain why you are doing the `salt = salt[:n]` and why not just compare saltLength to n?

Comment: @jcmiller11: See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @4of4: As a general rule, for any API, if an error is returned then, unless explicitly defined, assume that other return values are undefined. This implies that we usually check `err` first. However, for `io.Reader.Read`, `n` is well defined; it's the number of bytes read into `buf` before any error. Except for `n == 0`, `buf[:n]` will be passed to `// process read buffer`, where you can add a length test. After `// process read buffer` we check for errors. For example, assume `n, err := rdr.Read(buf[:cap(buf)])` returns `n == saltLength` where `saltLength > 0` and `err == io.ErrNoProgress`.